# grpc future stub failure

Tags: java, asynchronous, grpc

I'm creating a non-blocking stub like this:

```
stub = ServiceGrpc.newFutureStub(channel);
```

Then, when I make a call I use something like this:

```
ListenableFuture<SearchSubscriberResponse> searchSubscriberResponse = stub.withDeadlineAfter(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).searchSubscriber(searchSubscriberRequest);
Futures.addCallback(searchSubscriberResponse, futureCallback);
```

And the callback has 2 options, as I see:

```
void onSuccess(@Nullable V var1);
void onFailure(Throwable var1);
```

In my case DEADLINE_EXCEEDED happens often, but then onFailure only has a Throwable argument, so how can I correlate with the request that produced the failure? Or can't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different `futureCallback` for each request.

```
ListenableFuture<SearchSubscriberResponse> searchSubscriberResponse = stub
    .withDeadlineAfter(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .searchSubscriber(searchSubscriberRequest);
Futures.addCallback(searchSubscriberResponse,
    new YourFutureCallback(searchSubscriberRequest));
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric. My main concern would be the performance here - I will make a test today and if there is no decrease in performance, I will use this solution and accept the answer.